# How can I read a stream of JSON objects into browser

Tags: jquery, node.js, node.js-stream, highland.js, oboe.js

Given a `node.js` style object stream as the example below shows, how can this be read by an `http` request on a webpage and processed:

```
{"id":"one",   "value":"the first object"}
{"id":"two",   "value":"the second object"}
{"id":"three", "value":"the third object"}
```

Answer (score 4):

Progressively parsing an http request is something that oboe.js is good for.  What you're looking to send seems like something called JSON Lines. Technically, oboe only supports receiving a single valid JSON object or array. But I found that you can get it to work for your data :)

```js
oboe('/data.json')
  .node('{id value}', function(x) {
    console.log('object', x)
  })
  .node('!', function(x) {
    console.log('root', x)
  })
```

You can use `oboe` to a request to load the data (it uses a native XMLHttpRequest under the hood). Then you use `node` to add a listener for any object that has both an `id` property and a `values` property, or for any root level object with `!`. Note that you *do not* have to use both.

You can view a working example [here](https://square-gem.hyperdev.space/) and the source code [here](https://hyperdev.com/#!/project/square-gem).

*Gotcha*: One thing worth being aware of if you try to use oboe's `done` function is that it will trigger multiple times, once for each object. That's because each will be parsed as a full valid object.

Comment: i don't see any official documentation for the oboe.js

Comment: I think both the original site and my own fork were taken down with changes to Heroku. I am no longer involved in the project and it's now unmaintained. If you'd like to try running the site yourself, you can find the src at https://github.com/jimhigson/oboe.js-website